# How to get all phone numbers with labels for all contacts in address book?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I want to get all the phone numbers with diff labels like "iPhone", "home phone", "mobile number", "other numbers" , etc. for a contact stored in iPhone address book.

How do I get it?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

I am trying: which is crashing

```
ABAddressBookRef ab=ABAddressBookCreate();

    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);
    NSMutableArray *allNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CFArrayGetCount(people)];

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers); j++) {


            CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers, i);
            NSString *phoneLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, j);
            CFStringRef locLabel1 = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers, j);
            NSString *phoneLabel1 =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

             NSLog(@" ####### phone no -> %@ , phone label -> %@  #######)", locLabel1, phoneLabel1);
            //CFRelease(phones);
            NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
            CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
            CFRelease(locLabel);
            NSLog(@"phone no -> %@ , phone label -> %@)", phoneNumber, phoneLabel);
            [phoneNumber release];
        }
        CFRelease(numbers);
    }

    CFRelease(people);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef all = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex n = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, i);
    NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"Name %@", firstName);

    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
    {

        CFStringRef locLabel1 = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
        NSString *phoneLabel1 =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel1);

          NSLog(@"  ### %@  --- %@ ### )", locLabel1, phoneLabel1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
ABMultiValueRef *phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
{
   CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
   CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
   NSString *phoneLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

   NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
   CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
   CFRelease(locLabel);
   NSLog(@"  - %@ (%@)", phoneNumber, phoneLabel);

   [phoneNumber release];
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a `CFRelease(phones);` missing after the for loop?

Comment: "ABMultiValueRef *phones" should be changed to "ABMultiValueRef phones"

Answer (score 2):

This is solid for ARC 64bit iOS8:

```
- (NSArray *)phoneNumbersOfContactAsStrings:(ABRecordRef)contactRef {

NSMutableArray *mobilePhones = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray *allPhoneNumbers = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phones));

for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [allPhoneNumbers count]; i++) {
    if ([(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, (long)i)) isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel]) {
        [mobilePhones addObject:CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, (long)i))];
    }
    if ([(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, (long)i)) isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel]) {
        [mobilePhones addObject:CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, (long)i))];
    }
}

CFRelease(phones);
return mobilePhones;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also to get phone number with particular record id, do this:

```
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef all = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, indexPath.row);
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSLog(@"Name %@", firstName);

        NSInteger myID = ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);
        NSLog(@"Record id is > %d", myID);

        ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,myID);

        ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
        {

            NSString* num = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);

            CFStringRef locLabel1 = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);

            NSString *phoneLabel1 =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel1);

            NSLog(@"%@  --- %@ )", num, phoneLabel1);

        }
```